# The case of the disappearing QWidgets

Tags: qt, qt5, qtabwidget

I've noted some rather inscrutable behaviour from QTabWidget. I'm trying to detach and reattach tabs, and that works fine, except if I programmatically select a widget after reattaching it, all its children disappear! No about of update() or repaint() or whatever seems to make the widgets reappear. You can select a different tab and the re-select the "broken" tab, and the children widgets are automagically visible again.

Below is some (shortened) code that displays the problem.

```
void MainWindow::test()
{
    auto tab_widget = pimpl->tab_widget;
    auto sz = tab_widget->size();

    auto wgt = tab_widget->currentWidget();
    auto tab_text = tab_widget->tabText(tab_widget->currentIndex());
    if(wgt == nullptr)
    return;


    wgt->installEventFilter(new GenericQEventFilter(wgt, 
        [=] (QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {
            if(event->type() == QEvent::Close) {
                printf("Close Event!!!\n");
                tab_widget->addTab(wgt, tab_text);
                tab_widget->setCurrentWidget(wgt);
                // wgt's children are temporarily invisible
                wgt->setUpdatesEnabled(true);
                wgt->repaint();
                wgt->update();
                qApp->processEvents(); //NOTHING WORKS!!!
                return true;
             }
            return false;
        }));
    tab_widget->removeTab(tab_widget->currentIndex());
    wgt->setParent(nullptr);
    wgt->setVisible(true);
    wgt->raise();
    wgt->setFocus();
}
```

So, just to be clear, I'm attaching an event-fitler to the detached widget in order to pick up the onClose event. The event filter works fine, picks up the event, and reattaches the widget to the tab_widget; however, after reattaching, all the children are invisible or something crazy like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `adjustSize()`?  This would happen if for some reason it did not calculate a new size, and try to drop the objects in correctly.  Performing a `resize()` would do something similar, too.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#adjustSize

Also try `qDebug() << wgt->dumpObjectTree();` on any `QObject` that seems to be missing its children.  This would let you know if it has something to do with the parenting changes.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#children

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/debug.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#dumpObjectTree

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qdebug.html#details

And then there is also a possibility that they are in place but considered `hidden` and a show event didn't propagate down.  So you could call `show()` explicitly to check this.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#visible-prop

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#show

And there may be some other property of a `QTabWidget` I am not thinking of right off.  Look through this list and see if there are any others that might be related.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qtabwidget-members.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thank-you for the hints, that was very helpful. You lead me to a solution in the end. Calling `setVisible(true)` had no effect; however, I created a timer to call `show()` and that worked perfectly.

`QTimer::singleShot(20, wgt, SLOT(show())); // force children to re-appear`